# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 4

Tags: c#, datagridview

My datagridview has 4 rows. row[2] has the name of date1 and row[3] has the name of date2. I also tested this code with Cells[2] and Cell[3] instead of Cells name. But again i received the same error. The problem is that Index is not out of range. and is less than the size of the collection. This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv1frmModateEghamat.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows[i].Cells["date1"].Value);

            DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows[i].Cells["date2"].Value);

            TimeSpan span = date2.Subtract(date1);

            int result = int.Parse(span.TotalDays.ToString());

            if (result >= int.Parse(textBoxX2.Text))
            {
                dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows[i].Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {

                CurrencyManager cr = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dgv1frmModateEghamat.DataSource];
                cr.SuspendBinding();

                dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows[i].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

But I see this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: What lines is the error on ?

Comment: use the debugger and the QuickWatch and step through the lines and evaluate the rows[i].Cells["coluimn name"] change the value of `i` in the quick watch meaning the index value and see which one causes the error to show in the quickwatch window..

Comment: This line:DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows[i].Cells["date1"].Value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through Rows but indexing into SelectedRows.  You need to loop through SelectedRows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
```

Comment: I did this. the code does not give any error but it does not do anything either. Nothing happens when I click on this button. I have a gridveiw with columns name, family, date_start, date_finish in a hotel. I want to see people who have stayed for specific days, for example five days. I used this code. But now that I have changed it it does not do any thing.

Comment: Maybe you need to loop through Rows and index into Rows then.

Comment: Wherever it says SelectedRows in your code snippet, change it to Rows instead.

Answer (score 0):

`dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows` may have fewer items than `dgv1frmModateEghamat.Rows`.

Comment: How can I see that dgv1frmModateEghamat.SelectedRows has how many rows?